# Why does ActionMailer not deliver my mongoid object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, actionmailer

## Problem

I have an app where one can make pledges against a gift. Once a pledge is made, an email confirmation should be sent to pledger. Server is issuing `500 Internal Server Error` when attempting to mail.

Context:

- Ruby on Rails 3.2.0
- Actionmailer 3.2.0
- Mongoid 2.4.3
- Thin 1.3.1

I've used Actionmailer on previous apps, but this is my first time working with Mongoid.

## Code

```rb
class Pledge
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, :type => String
  field :email, :type => String
  field :amount, :type => Float

  embedded_in :gift
end 


class PledgesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @gift = Gift.find(params[:gift_id])
    @pledge = @gift.pledges.new(params[:pledge])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @pledge.save
        PledgeMailer.pledge_confirmation(@pledge).deliver
        format.html { redirect_to :root, notice: 'Pledge successfully created.' }
      else
        ...
      end
    end
  end
...
end


class PledgeMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "no-reply@mail.com"

  def pledge_confirmation(pledge)
    @pledge = pledge
    mail(:to => pledge.email, :subject => "Thanks - pledge confirmation")
  end
end
```

## Log

So let's say `Sam Andreas` at `sacrificial.address@gmail.com` pledged `$42.42` for gift `4f2695009f5b7f3464000001`.

This happily saves to Mongodb and redirects to `:root`. With adding the call to `PledgeMailer`, we get:

```
Started POST "/gifts/4f2695009f5b7f3464000001/pledges" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-08 14:13:21 +1100
Processing by PledgesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"EwgOwALSb8uUsT4Ow1+RBvAEihXKXoqKS1JA9ZfpUfg=", 
    "pledge"=>{"name"=>"Sam Andreas", "email"=>"sacrificial.address@gmail.com", "amount"=>"42.42"}, 
    "commit"=>"Create Pledge", "gift_id"=>"4f2695009f5b7f3464000001"}
  MONGODB danspressie_development['gifts'].find({:_id=>BSON::ObjectId('4f2695009f5b7f3464000001')}).limit(-1).sort([[:_id, :asc]])
  MONGODB danspressie_development['gifts'].update({"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('4f2695009f5b7f3464000001')}, {"$push"=>{"pledges"=>{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('4f31e8519f5b7f41d1000002'), "name"=>"Sam Andreas", "email"=>"sacrificial.address@gmail.com", "amount"=>42.42}}})
  Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 11ms

SyntaxError (/Users/daniel/Dropbox/dev/src/danspressie/app/mailers/pledge_mailer.rb:4: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
/Users/daniel/Dropbox/dev/src/danspressie/app/mailers/pledge_mailer.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end 
  def pledge_confirmation(pledge)
 ^):
  app/controllers/pledges_controller.rb:8:in `block in create'
  app/controllers/pledges_controller.rb:6:in `create'
```

Struggling hard, but can't see where the error is in `pledge_confirmation`.

Do you have any pointers? :)

Comment: Try `cat -v pledge_mailer.rb`, that should show where any strange bytes are.

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks! I didn't spot other bytes. But I recreated it as per Mischa's answer and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks fine. The error is complaining about an "invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)". You'd better recreate `pledge_mailer.rb` from scratch and save it with charset UTF-8 instead of US-ASCII.